# Query to count employees for each manger(also zero count for manager)

Tags: mysql

Manager table :

```
create table Manager(id integer, name varchar(100));
insert into Manager(id, name) values(1, "M1");
insert into Manager(id, name) values(2, "M2");
insert into Manager(id, name) values(3, "M3");
```

Employee table along with manager id(m_id)

```
create table Employee(id integer, m_id integer, name varchar(100));
insert into Employee(id, m_id, name) values(11, 1,"E1");
insert into Employee(id, m_id, name) values(12, 1,"E2");
insert into Employee(id, m_id, name) values(13, 2,"E3");
```

Executed query:

```
select M.id, M.name, count(E.id) from Manager as M, Employee as E where E.m_id=M.id group by E.m_id, M.id, M.name;
```

Output:

```
1   M1  2
2   M2  1
```

Expected output:

```
1   M1  2
2   M2  1
3   M3  0
```

Please help me how to include **M3** manager along with **0** employee assigned to him?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a left join

```
SELECT M.id, M.name, count(E.id) from Manager as M LEFT JOIN Employee as E ON E.m_id=M.id GROUP BY E.m_id, M.id, M.name;
```